# SketchUp: how to make a pipe joint?

Tags: sketchup

In sketchup, I have a solid box. I want to extract a portion of the box so when you look at it, it looks like a mold. Picture 3 vertical pipes with a horizontal pipe connection all three of them at the bottom. It looks like this:

```
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
\-------/
```

The bottom left and right corners are pipe joints, 90 degree bends. The center pipe forms a T intersection. How can I draw this in SketchUp 8?

Answer (score 0):

**Corner Pipe Joint**

Use quart of [a torus](http://www.cad-addict.com/2010/07/sketchup-drawing-torus-spheres-and.html) to form a corner Pipe Joint, then connect the cilinders to it.

**Middle Pipe Joint**

Just end your middle cilinder in the middle of the bottom cilinder, if you want it rounded then use two toruses.

Comment: Okay - that makes sense. But what about extruding it from the "box?"